# View all requests made by Firebase in my iOS app

Tags: ios, firebase

I would like to debug my Firebase app and I need to see all requests made by Firebase. Is that possible?

One of my requests is returning an empty result, but I am unsure what the request actually is.

Comment: All the requests that are made by you to firebase are returned as promises which means you should be able to monitor them right in your app and check the results. Please add some code as to how you are making those requests, etc and someone might be able to help.

Comment: @TheeBen I was more wondering if I could see the URLs of the requests.

Comment: I am still not sure if I understand what you mean. Are you talking about the POST/GET requests that Firebase makes? I'm not sure you would really need to worry about that. If you have an error in your app it's most likely from your side, either your data or something in your code. I'm not sure how to make those request appear in xcode, but in Chrome Dev tools you can simply opt in to see all XMLHttpRequests and monitor them all. Perhaps xcode has something similar but I'm not sure.

Comment: @TheeBen That is what I was referring to. I'm new to Firebase so I just needed a way to debug it.

Comment: You most likey don't need to go that deep for debugging your issue. I have never had to do that and have been working with Firebase for quite awhile now. It's most likely something in your side or the data in your database. Good luck